# NodeJS Passport configured per route, added as middleware and getting no errors but it does not work/fire

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I have a NodeJS Api and I authenticate with Passport Azure AD Bearer Token -- all is fine when I configure this globally but in order to be able to keep it clean I need to configure it per route file.

I have taken the logic on the front page and just added it inside the route file as middleware but it does not seem to fire:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
passport.initialize()
passport.use(bearerStrategy);
passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false })
next();
})
```

The config objects are also present above this code.

Comment: That's not how Express or Passport work, though. I'm not sure if Passport can handle multiple calls to `passport.initialize` and `passport.use` (with the same strategy), and `passport.authenticate` is a middleware, not a regular function.

Comment: @robertklep hmm -- so I should just initialize passport on index.js and then configure it per middleware with passport.use and .authenticate? 

Or am I stuck adding the authenticate to each specific route in the page?

Comment: I think that both `passport.initialize` and `passport.use` should go in `index.js`, because they should be called during app initialization (and not during a request). You insert `passport.authenticate` into each route handler that needs it (but that's typically just one. If you want to clean things up, you can move all passport-related  initialization code to a separate file, of course, and load that up in `index.js`.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks -- do you think there's no way to move the passport.use inside the route itself? The thing is, that bearerStrategy object contains all the config information for Azure, including the clientID which I'd like to be different in each page as it would be a different app registered in Azure AD

Comment: You can't move it inside a request handler. Do you have a fixed number of apps that you need to access? Because you _can_ `passport.use` different instances of the same strategy by giving each one a different name (and pass that name as argument to `passport.authenticate` for the relevant page).

Comment: @robertklep I think the number of apps will be mostly fixed and fairly low (10-20 depending on stage) and manually adding passport strategies together with writing the routes should be ok in this quantity. 

I will go this way then and add multiple passport strategies in the main file for each app. Thanks!

Comment: @robertklep So the solution was to just rename all passport-related stuff and options something like passport_appName and then when mentioning the authentication on the main route handler for that file. If you want to post it as an answer I'm happy to mark it as the right answer as you did help me find out what to do exactly. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if I understand how you solved it. You can also answer your own question if you found a method that works, and might be beneficial to others :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up renaming my passport config objects and initalization objects with an added _appname for each app and initialized them all in the index.js and then simply mentioning on the parent route which passport instance protects which.

Code below:

```
    // MIDDLEWARE    
    app.use(passport_myAppName.initialize());
    passport_myAppName.use(bearerStrategy_myAppName)

    app.use(passport_mySecondApp.initialize());
    passport_mySecondApp.use(bearerStrategy_mySecondApp)

    // ROUTES
    app.use("/myAppName", passport_idtTV.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }), myAppName);
    app.use("/mySecondApp", passport_idtTV.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }), mySecondApp);
```